# Angular $http.get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" No file reference, let alone a line number

Tags: json, angularjs, express

I'm at my rope's end on this one.  I am getting this error in seemingly random places in my app.  Raven reports them from a couple dozen locations but I can only replicate a couple locally.  It seems to me that the problem has something to do with the parsing of the JSON response but the responses are valid.

In my Angular service...

```
...
getThread: function(id, success, error) {
    $http.get('/message/'+id).success(function(data){
        success(data);
    }).error(error);
}
...
```

In my Express controller...

```
...
res.json(mssgs);
...
```

Here's a sample response...

```
[
  {
    "id": 79,
    "body": "test",
    "senderArchived": false,
    "recipientArchived": false,
    "createdAt": "2014-04-17T01:44:46.762Z",
    "updatedAt": "2014-04-17T01:44:46.762Z",
    "RootMessageId": 69,
    "SenderId": 164050,
    "RecipientId": 154040,
    "sender": {
      "username": "boca",
      "id": 164050,
      "primaryMedium": null
    },
    "recipient": {
      "username": "quimby",
      "id": 154040,
      "primaryMedium": {
        "id": "186",
        "type": "image",
        "nativeURL": "https://domain/imageurl.jpg",
        "mediumURL": "https://domain/imageurl.jpg",
        "smallURL": "https://domain/imageurl.jpg",
        "createdAt": "2014-04-21T15:52:10.927Z",
        "updatedAt": "2014-04-21T15:52:10.947Z",
        "CommentId": null,
        "EventId": null,
        "UserId": 154040,
        "PostId": null,
        "MessageId": null,
        "MediaFolderId": null
      }
    },
    "messageMedia": []
  }
]
```

In both Chrome and Safari this results in error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"

Here's the request headers from Chrome...

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3001
Request URL:https://localhost:3001/message/69
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:streamLoc=%7B%22distance%22%3A-1%2C%22locName%22%3A%22%22%7D; usePostLocation=yes; connect.sid=s%3AhX37rupUct2jut4yApN1GIH9.n5nPURTMXl5OKd46rMqeRc4bg1Q%2F%2Bky0El2r%2BcBvC8c; user=%7B%22id%22%3A154040%2C%22role%22%3A%7B%22bitMask%22%3A32%2C%22title%22%3A%22admin%22%7D%2C%22username%22%3A%22quimby%22%2C%22emailVerified%22%3Atrue%2C%22verified%22%3Atrue%7D
Host:localhost:3001
Referer:https://localhost:3001/messages
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36

Response Headers
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1115
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 29 Apr 2014 02:41:47 GMT
ETag:"485872145"
X-Powered-By:Express
```

Every other similar question has pointed to JSONP or actual syntax problems but I'm not using JSONP and there are not any code syntax problems.

Comment: A minification problem? Try running with use strict?

Comment: Nope.  Strict mode enabled already.  No minification.

Comment: does .error() expect a function?

Comment: Seconding @richgreen. Is the `error` argument in your `.error()` call a function? Edit: Never mind, I see it. You're passing in callbacks to the `getThread` function. Can you post the code for your success and error functions? There may be a syntax issue there, who knows.

Comment: Download the non-minified version of AngularJS and debug the soure code.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know your exact situation, I can't provide the exact anwer. However, this is my try.

I see that your service is not returning anything, but processing success and error functions within it.

```
getThread: function(id, success, error) {
    $http.get('/message/'+id).success(function(data){
        success(data);
    }).error(error);
}
```

1. Is your error(error) is correct? I assume you are passing error function as a parameter, but I see inconsistency between `success(data)` and `error`
2. This is recommendation. I think you should change your service only return promise, and do not process anything. So, it should look like this.

   ```
   getThread: function(id) {
      return $http.get('/message/'+id);
   }
   ```

   Then your controller handles success and error, so that you can see all success messages and error messages. So, controller will have a code like the following

   ```
   MyService.getThread(id).then( 
     function(data) {....}, 
     function(error) {....}
   }
   ```

Having data processing logic in your controller will give you much more difficulty in debugging.

I would recommend you to process http data in your controller, not in a service.

Answer (score 1):

- Your error seems related to some JSon parsing function
- Your sample response header say "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Given this, looks that you don't need to use any parsing function, something is missing.

If you can not always reproduce it, I would enable recording network calls, so you can see retrieve exactly what response(s) give troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passsing a null as id in

```
getThread: function(id, success, error) {
    $http.get('/message/'+id).success(function(data){
        success(data);
    }).error(error);
}
```

That would give you a syntax error when resolving $http.get('/message/'+)

Insert a test for null before the $http call and wait for it to be hit.

Comment: actually null is casted to string..String('/message/'+null) = 'message/null'

Comment: Yep you are right. An empty string would do the job though!